# Fadeout <body> in js when video ending and redirect to other site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm using script and video.js in my website - I make video cutscene - you click to link the index.html fadeout and fadein cutscene.html - we see movie for 10 secound and if the movie end we go to contact.html

And all working very nice but i have got only problem with fadeout when movie it's end

This is my codes

Custon.js in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").css("display", "none");
    $("body").fadeIn(2000);
    $("a").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        linkLocation = this.href;
        $("body").delay(2000).fadeOut(2000, redirectPage);
    });

    function redirectPage() {
        if (location.href.indexOf('reload') == -1) location.replace(location.href + '?reload');
        window.location = linkLocation;
    }
});
```

And video script:

```
<video id="movie-id" class="video-js vjs-default-skin alignleft" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" controls preload="auto" autoplay data-setup="{}">
    <source src="oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    <source src="oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
    <source src="oceans-clip.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
</video>
```

And script with redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_V_("video_background").ready(function () {
    var myPlayer = this;
    myPlayer.play();
    myPlayer.addEvent("ended", function () {
        window.location = "contact.html"
    });
});
</script>
```

How to add fadeout effect when video end?
Please help me. I really search 5 days this answer.
Thanks a lot,
Arleta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the fadout in the `ended` event handler:

```
myPlayer.addEvent("ended", function () {
    $('body').fadeOut(2000, function() {
        window.location = "contact.html"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you - it's working awesome! :)

You are cool. For 8 minutes i accept your answer. :)